# Ios Swift TableView limpada ao retornar a tela

Tags: ios, swift

Estou implementando duas telas... na primeira tenho um tableview a ao clicar em uma das celulas, envio dados para a segunda tela...

Porem quando clico no botao de voltar que é uma segue para a primeira tela...os dados que carreguei na tableView, são perdidos...

Como faço pra retornar a primeira tela, sem modificar os dados que estão na tableview?

Obrigado

Comment: Como você está chamando a segunda tela e em seguida voltando para a primeira? Poste o código para que possamos ajuda-lo.

Comment: Você esta fazendo via navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você está utilizando outra **segue** para voltar para a pagina. Isso faz que recrie a pagina novamente, dando start no viewDidLoad se não me engano. Como não tem imagens do seu código, estou supondo que esteja utilizando o reloadData da tabela no viewDidLoad. Por isso que está recriando a tabela novamente. Sugiro que estude navegação entre telas.Um exemplo seria o *dismissViewControllerAnimated* , utilizando para voltar para a pagina anterior.